# MYSQL Update incl. ROUND failes in #1064

Tags: mysql, rounding, mysql-error-1064

I want to perform a simple update my values with rounding them and substracting -1:

```
UPDATE
catalog_product_entity_decimal
SET
catalog_product_entity_decimal.value= round(catalog_product_entity_decimal.value,-1)-1
WHERE
catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id="76";
```

The error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')-1 FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` WHERE
>   catalog_product_entity_decimal.a' at line 1

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: By using `ROUND(.., -1)`, you are rounding to nearest **tens**. So, 11.5 will round to 10. Are you sure that you want to do this ?

Comment: You are sure you posted right query?  There are no syntax error in that query.  Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Yes - the query is right.
My goal is to round every number to ending 9, that’s the reason I round to 10 and substract 1.

But the error appears